# Determine the breaking point or turning point of payment methods with plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have data of how people pay their invoices. It can be either 'eCheck' or 'Credit Card'. I want to plot the data and show if there is a pattern on how people pay based on the dollar amount.

I was thinking about creating a histogram with ggplot and grouping the bars by 'eCheck' or 'Credit Card'. The problem is figuring how to bin my numbers.

I am open to any suggestions and comments. Thanks!

Here's a sample of my data:

```
PaymentType Dollar Amount
eCheck      114
eCheck      114
Credit Card 39
Credit Card 16
eCheck      16
Credit Card 114
Credit Card 228
Credit Card 228
eCheck      228
Credit Card 16
eCheck      342
Credit Card 114
```

EDIT: RESPONSE TO jlhoward's METHOD.

The density plot does not show a "breaking point" between 'Credit Cards' and 'eChecks'. They both seem to follow a similar distribution.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = TotTransAmt, fill = PayMethodDesc2)) +
  stat_bin(aes(y = ..density..), position = 'identity', color = 'lightblue') +
  stat_density(alpha = .6, position = 'identity', color = 'blue') +
  xlim(0,500)
```

[image]

Coefficient 'TotTransAmt' has a very low p-value suggesting it is highly significant in predicting payment type. The plot shows that users are more likely to use credit cards for a lower amount. However, it does not show echecks have a high probability usage.

```
model <- glm(PayMethodDesc2 ~ TotTransAmt, data = df, family = 'binomial')
summary(model)$coefficients

                 Estimate   Std. Error    z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -2.8062540381 5.827325e-03 -481.56817 0.000000e+00
TotTransAmt  0.0006005004 3.196051e-05   18.78882 9.322726e-79


ggplot(df, aes(x=TotTransAmt)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=as.numeric(PayMethodDesc2)-1,color=PayMethodDesc2)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x)predict(model, newdata=data.frame(TotTransAmt=x), type="response"))+
  labs(y="P(eCheck)")
```

[image]

I modeled my data with svm. I used 7% as my training and 5% as my test data because it was taking too long with 70/30. There seems to be a high error in predicting eChecks. However, predicting Credit Cards is 100%. Could this be because of the size of my dataset? I have 833749 Credit Card values and 53964 eCheck values. This relates back to my question: should I undersample or oversample my data to get an even amount on both factors?

Based on my current findings is it safe to assume there is no dollar amount that creates a turning point and that both methods are used arbitrarily?

```
library(e1071)
train <- df[sample(1:nrow(df),round(nrow(df)*.07)),]
test <- df[sample(1:nrow(df),round(nrow(df)*.05)),]
model <- svm(PayMethodDesc2 ~ TotTransAmt, train)
table(act=train$PayMethodDesc2, pred = predict(model,train))

             pred
act           Credit Card eCheck
  Credit Card       58347      0
  eCheck             3788      5



table(act=test$PayMethodDesc2,  pred=predict(model, test))

             pred
act           Credit Card eCheck
  Credit Card       41646      0
  eCheck             2740      0
```

Comment: The second column represents amount of money in $, right? You want to predict if someone is going to pay by check or card, given that you know the amount?

Comment: Yes the 2nd column is money. Right now I do not want to predict. I want to see if there is a breaking point.

Comment: So, breaking point means that there's an amount A that -for example- above it people pay by card, and under it people pay by check. It is a way of prediction and you can find that by using a classification tree to split your variable "amount" in terms of probability to pay by check or card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, there are lots of ways to do this. I'd be inclined to start by overlaying the distributions with density plots. Your sample has too few cases for this to be useful, so the code below creates an artificial example with 2000 cases. In this example, eCheck payments are normally distributed with mean = $100 and sd = $25, and Credit Card payments are normally distributed with mean= $200.

```
set.seed(1)     # for reproducible example
DA <- c(rnorm(1000, mean=100, sd=25), rnorm(1000, mean=200, sd=25))
PT <- rep(c("eCheck", "Credit Card"), each=1000)
df <- data.frame(PT,DA)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=DA, fill=PT)) + 
  stat_bin(aes(y=..density..),position="identity", color="lightblue") +
  stat_density(alpha=0.5,position="identity", color="blue")
```

[image]

You can see that there is a "break" at about $150 (no surprise there), but that about 2.5% of the eCheck payments were for more than that, and that 2.5% of the Credit Card payments were less than that.

You say in the comments that you don't want to model but one way to assess if there is a break is to restate the problem as: does Dollar Amount have a significant effect on whether one pays by eCheck or Credit Card? As suggested in another answer you can do this with logistic regression:

```
model <- glm(PT ~DA, data=df, family="binomial")
summary(model)$coefficients
#               Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept) 22.8205378 1.67587743  13.61707 3.170403e-42
# DA          -0.1526074 0.01115254 -13.68364 1.271643e-42
```

Since the `DA` coefficient has a p-value ~ 10<sup>-42</sup> there is no doubt that `DA` is important in predicting payment type. The logistic model predicts the probability of one or the other payment type based on `DA`, which we can visualize as below.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=DA)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=as.numeric(PT)-1,color=PT)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x)predict(model, newdata=data.frame(DA=x), type="response"))+
  labs(y="P(eCheck)")
```

[image]

So in this contrived example, payments < ~$125 are almost certainly by eCheck, and payments > ~$175 are almost certainly by CC. Between those limits uncertainty increases. Payments ~$150, can go either way, with about equal probability.

Finally, you can think about this as a two-way classification problem in one variable (this is about as simple as it gets). One way to solve those is using so-called support vector machines (SVM). This is similar to the `rpart` approach but at least [one reference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf) that compares the two methods claims that SVM is more reliable.

```
library(e1071)      # for svm(...)
indx  <- sample(1:nrow(df),200)        # 200 random row numbers
train <- df[indx,]                     # training set
test  <- df[-indx,]                    # test set
model <- svm(PT~DA, train)             # build model with training set
table(act=train$PT, pred=predict(model,train))     # test model against training set
#              pred
# act           Credit Card eCheck
#   Credit Card          91      4
#   eCheck                4    101
```

So in the training set, of 95 cases that were in fact CC transactions, 91 were predicted correctly; of 105 eCheck transactions, 101 were predicted correctly. Similarly, applying the model to the test set:

```
table(act=test$PT,  pred=predict(model, test))     # test model against test set  
#              pred
# act           Credit Card eCheck
#   Credit Card         884     21
#   eCheck               23    872
```

So when testing the model (created based on the training set), against the test set, of 905 CC transactions, 884 were predicted correctly; of 895 eCheck transactions, 872 were predicted correctly.

---

EDIT: Response to OP's comment.

The notion of a "break point" is not a yes-no proposition. The question is: how well does a boundary value distinguish between categories (eCheck vs. CC)? In the example above, we could run SVM on the whole dataset.

```
model <- svm(PT~DA, df)
prop.table(table(act=df$PT,pred=predict(model,df)),margin=1)
#              pred
# act           Credit Card eCheck
#   Credit Card       0.974  0.026
#   eCheck            0.026  0.974
```

So both Credit Card and eCheck transactions are predicted correctly 97.4% of the time (because we set it up that way).

Now suppose the distributions showed much more overlap:

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducibility
DA <- c(rnorm(1000, mean=100, sd=25), rnorm(1000, mean=110, sd=25))
df <- data.frame(PT,DA)
model <- svm(PT~DA, df)
prop.table(table(act=df$PT,pred=predict(model,df)),margin=1)
#              pred
# act           Credit Card eCheck
#   Credit Card       0.615  0.385
#   eCheck            0.457  0.543
```

So in this case, where the mean amount for eCheck is $100 and the mean amount for CC is $110, the distributions overlap almost completely. Yet 
CC transactions are predicted correctly 62% of the time, and eCheck transactions are predicted correctly 54% of the time.

Comment: Thanks! My data's range is from 0.01 to 8000. Should I remove outliers before plotting density plot?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by outliers. Generally an outlier is either an error or a case which is known to have a different distribution  than the data of interest. So for instance if `0.01` means the transaction was cancelled, then definitely yes. On the other hand if some of the transactions were actually $0.01 then they should be included. I'd be inclined to leave everything in at the beginning.

Comment: Oh ok. If my density plot does not show a clear distinction, should I bin the amounts and re-plot it? If there is no clear distinction after that should I conclude that there is no "breaking point"?

Comment: `stat_bin(...)` already bins the amounts. You could try a different `binwidth` but I doubt that would change anything. Regarding the question: is there a break point, see my edits above.

Comment: can you review my work and suggest improvements? Thanks

Comment: It looks like the model predicts Credit Card for all transactions. This might be because the dataset 16 X as many CC as eCheck transactions. There is a parameter `class.weights` in `svm(...)` that compensates for asymmetric class sizes. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

There are various models to use when you have a scale\continuous independent variable and a binary dependent variable. But, you should (strictly) specify your objective, otherwise you'll get lost in the options you have.

Logistic regression is one option and especially useful when you want to investigate relationships between variables, as the output includes coefficients for interpretation.

I'd suggest a classification tree if your main objective is to spot a breaking point. Trees don't give you coefficients, but they group your variables with respect to a probability of interest:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

set.seed(121)
payment = c(rep("card",100), rep("check",100))
amount = c(round(rnorm(100,150,30)), round(rnorm(100,230,50)))

# my simple example dataset
dt = data.frame(payment,amount)

# build model
model = rpart(payment~amount, data = dt)

# plot model
prp(model,nn=T,varlen=10,type=4,extra=104)

# get rules (only for the terminal nodes)
path.rpart(model, 
           row.names(model$frame[model$frame$var== "<leaf>",]))
```

If you run this script you'll see that the model suggests that $189 is a breaking point based on the dataset we had. It also tells you that < 189 leads to 87% probability to pay with card and 13% to pay by check. Similarly you can interpret >= 189.

I really enjoyed the example provided by @jhoward, so in order to support that break point around $150 you can run the tree approach :

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

set.seed(1)     # for reproducible example
DA <- c(rnorm(1000, mean=100, sd=25), rnorm(1000, mean=200, sd=25))
PT <- rep(c("eCheck", "Credit Card"), each=1000)
df <- data.frame(PT,DA)


# build model
model = rpart(PT~DA, data = df)

# plot model
prp(model,nn=T,varlen=10,type=4,extra=104)

# get rules (only for the terminal nodes)
path.rpart(model, 
           row.names(model$frame[model$frame$var== "<leaf>",]))
```

and get the break at $151:
[image]

If you want to make your model more "sensitive" in terms of splits you can use the rpart.control specification like : `model = rpart(PT~DA, data = df, control = rpart.control(cp = ?, maxdepth = ?))` where you can try different values for cp and maxdepth.

Another option is to create a different tree using the package "party" or "partykit" and the command "ctree" to create a tree that splits based on p-values. For more info : http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html .

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. So my original data set has 38465 Credit Cards and 4494 eChecks. The model only has one node. Should that be sufficient or do I have to do some undersampling?

Comment: You mean there are no splits, right? You might need to make the model a little bit more sensitive (you specify a parameter within the model), or try a different tree model. I can update my answer if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption that a "breaking point" exists --- i.e., that the relationship is some sort of step function --- is a strong one that I would urge you to probe empirically before proceeding as if it were true.

To do that, I would use logistic regression with smoothing splines to check for a nonlinear relationship. Let's assume your data set is named `data` and the column with the payment methods is `payment.method`.

```
library(gam)
data$eCheck.d <- ifelse(data$payment.method=="eCheck", 1, 0)
model <- gam(eCheck.d ~ s(money), data = data)
plot(model, se=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters I would do a boxplot for each of the categories and compare visually differences in the distribution.

**Data**

```
d <- structure(list(PaymentType = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
     1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("CreditCard", "eCheck"), 
     class = "factor"), 
     DollarAmount = c(114L, 114L, 39L, 16L, 16L, 114L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 
                      16L, 342L, 114L)), 
     .Names = c("PaymentType", "DollarAmount"), 
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

**Plot**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = PaymentType, y = DollarAmount)) + geom_boxplot() + 
    coord_flip()
```

**Interpretation**

You see that the median for both payment types is very similiar, yet for `eCheck` people tend to spend more higher amounts. You also could look at the quartiles and see that for `eCheck` the 1st quartile = median indicating etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the focus is on plotting, then I would suggest another variation of the ideas proposed in the answer of @jlhoward. This showed the conditional distribution of "dollar amount" (`DA`) given the "payment type" (`PT`), using histograms or densities. The same is true for the boxplots proposed by @thothal which show the conditional distribution of `DA` given `PT`.

But the underlying question is the other way round: What is the distribution of `PT` conditional on `DA`. There are many statistical models for analyzing this connection which can again be visualized, as proposed in other replies here (e.g., using logistic regression, classification trees, etc.)

Furthermore, there is the option to do this in a completely exploratory way. Base R provides so-called spineplots/spinograms (`spineplot()`) and conditional density plots (`cdplot()`) for this situation. The idea is to simply visualize P(y | x) via P(x | y) * P(y) / P(x) where either histograms or kernel densities can be used for P(.).

Using the artificial example of @jlhoward:

```
set.seed(1)
DA <- c(rnorm(1000, mean=100, sd=25), rnorm(1000, mean=200, sd=25))
PT <- rep(c("eCheck", "Credit Card"), each=1000)
df <- data.frame(PT,DA)
```

I can then do

```
plot(PT ~ DA, data = df) ## internally calls spineplot()
plot(PT ~ DA, data = df, breaks = seq(0, 300, by = 50)) ## custom breaks for hist()
cdplot(PT ~ DA, data = df)
cdplot(PT ~ DA, data = df, bw = 2) ## custom bandwidth for density()
```

[image: plots]

See `?spineplot` and `?cdplot` for more details and examples.